# Update User Profile in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having a hardtime updating User Profile in my Edit Profile activity.  In my EditProfile, I've used this following codes to retrieve data from users like email, fullname, username and password:

```
    public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    EditText setEmail, setFullname, setUsername, setPassword;
    Button buttonLogout, buttonUpdate;
    ProgressBar progressBar3;

    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    String userId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

       setEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEdit);
       setFullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullnameEdit);
       setUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEdit);
       setPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);

        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        progressBar3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateButton);


        progressBar3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Logging Out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                }, 2000);

            }
        });

user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
userId =user.getUid();


    reference.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            User userProfile =snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if(userProfile != null){
                String sEmail = userProfile.getEmail;
                String sFullname = userProfile.getFullname;
                String sUsername  = userProfile.getUsername;
                String sPassword = userProfile.getPassword;

                setEmail.setText(sEmail);
                setFullname.setText(sFullname);
                setUsername.setText(sUsername);
                setPassword.setText(sPassword);
            }
        }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Something went wrong!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Now any of you guys have some idea on how to update profile using this approach? Cause some of the codes uses Intent in their Login to pass the values, but here I didn't but the values are right. Here is my login code (the else statement):

```
progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(getEmail, getPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if(user.isEmailVerified()){
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditProfile.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                        else{
                            user.sendEmailVerification();
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Email not Verified! Check your email for verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Failed to Login! Please check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

For additional Info, this is my User class:

public class User {

```
public String getEmail, getFullname, getUsername, getPassword;

public User(){

}

public User(String getEmail, String getFullname, String getUsername, String getPassword){
    this.getEmail = getEmail;
    this.getFullname = getFullname;
    this.getUsername = getUsername;
    this.getPassword = getPassword;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There are no errors in this code, but my problem is where do I start or how do I start in updating profile, since all the youtube vids are using different approach like using Intent.getstringextra and Datasnapshot in their editprofile to pass values.  I don't know where to start cause i cannot see vids or codes using this retrieve data much as update data

Comment: I've tried using Intent intent =getIntent(); then String userEmail =intent.gettingStringExtra("getEmail") but that doesn't seem to work in edit profile since I got the values of email, username, fullname, and password in editprofile using those codes.  Now majority of tutorials are using intent in login and using showdata() in edit profile to pass values but this mine is different so I don't know where to start.